# Find $\int{\frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find $\int{\frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^x}}dx$

I did the following substitution:
$u=e^x\Rightarrow du=e^x dx\Rightarrow \int{\frac{u}{1+u}du}=\int1du-\int\frac{1}{u+1}du=u-\ln{u}=e^x-\ln{(e^x+1)}+C $

I know this is the correct answer, however my initial approach was as follows:
$u=1+e^x\Rightarrow du=e^xdx $ and $e^x=u-1\Rightarrow \int\frac{u-1}{u}=\int1du-\int\frac{1}{u}du=u-\ln u=1+e^x-\ln (1+e^x)+C$. Are these two answers equivalent due to the arbitrariness of the constant? Or is there an error in what I did in my substitution of $u=1+e^x$

Comment: Yes, the constant $C$ completely absorbs the $1$...

Comment: How did you go from $e^{2 x}$ to just $u$ in the numerator??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork since $e^2x = (e^x)^2$ then one of those gets taken care of with the $du = e^x dx$ and the other $e^x$ can be replaced with $u$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same answer, for the reason that you have mentioned:$$1+e^x-\ln(1+e^x)+C=e^x-\ln(1+e^x)+C'$$if we take $C'=C+1$.